# Unable to update (404 Not Found)

Tags: apt, updates

I am having issues updating, apologies in advance I am a novice in this sort of stuff.

```
    tom@ubuntu:/etc$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease [256 kB]
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-security InRelease
Ign:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 InRelease
Hit:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 Release
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe arm64 Packages
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe Translation-en [5951 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe arm64 DEP-11 Metadata [3516 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe arm64 c-n-f Metadata [295 kB]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe arm64 Packages
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe arm64 Packages
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
Fetched 256 kB in 5s (56.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/mantic/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)